# On the boundary of a simply connected set

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology

Let $U$ be an open simply connected subset of $\mathbb R^2$. Let $x$ be a boundary point of $U$.

Does then there always exist a continuous function $f\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb R^2\setminus U$ such that $x = f(0)\ne f(1)$?

That is, does then there always exist a nontrvial continuous curve starting at $x$ and staying outside $U$?

Comment: This gives nothing towards the general case, but if $\partial U$ is locally connected, Torhorst's theorem on continuous extension of conformal mappings gives that you can even take $f([0,1]) \subset \partial U$.

Comment: The answer is no. There are connected compacts, such that no 2 points can be connected by a path. You may consider a complement to such compact.

Comment: @OlegEroshkin, yes, you have answered the OP's Question -- great! One may consider the Knaster's pseudo-arc.

Comment: @OlegEroshkin ; Thank you for your comment. Can you give a reference to such compacts? Also, will their complement be simply connected?

Comment: @mme : Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @IosifPinelis One such compact is already mentioned by Wlod. It's called pseudo-arc, because it's (topologically) homogeneous.

Comment: @OlegEroshkin : I think the main problem with your idea is that the complement to any nonempty compact subset of $\mathbb R^2$ is not simply connected.

Comment: This MO answer https://mathoverflow.net/a/210708/112504 seems to mention I think a counterexample (again some sort of "pseudo-arc") to your question if you furthermore restrict $f$ to map only to the boundary $\partial U$ (even for $U$ with many nice properties). You could try to massage these pseudo-arc constructions to make something that works for your problem, maybe somehow stitching infinitely many of these compact pseudo-arcs together end-to-end to produce a very crooked ray from $0$ stumbling away to $\infty$, so that its complement $U$ is some sort of simply connected "slit domain".

Comment: @IosifPinelis That's not an obstacle. We just need that a compact with connected complement. Then you consider a disk containing the compact and cut along a (part of a) radius to obtain a simply connected domain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a variant of Fernando Muro's construction.

Let $X$ be the closure in $\mathbb R^2$of the graph of the function
$g(x):=x\sin\big(1/\sin(1/x)\big)$ defined on $[0,+\infty)\setminus\{1/n\pi:n\in \mathbb Z_+\}$. Let $U:=\mathbb R^2\setminus X$, again a simply connected open set. The function $g$  has a set of essential discontinuities $\{1/n\pi:n\in \mathbb Z_+\}$ that accumulates at $0$, but it is continuous at $0$, so $X$ has no points with $0$ first coordinate but $(0,0)$, and $(0,0)$  can be connected by continuous arcs to no other point of $X$ .

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 7):

No. Let $U=\mathbb{R}^2-X$ where $X$ is the closure of the image of $f\colon (0,+\infty)\to\mathbb{R}^2$, $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$. The point $(0,0)$, which is in the boundary of $U$ (as any other point in $X$), cannot be connected to $(1/\pi,0)$ with a path in $X$. Actually, no point with trivial first coordinate can be corrected to a point with non trivial first coordinate.

Comment: Hot but not enough -- this doesn't answer the OP's Question.

Comment: It does answer the question as stated when this answer was posted.

Comment: Fernando, you are right, I am very sorry! Indeed, I have "*improved*" on the original question, mea culpa.

Comment: @FernandoMuro : Thank you for your answer. However, it does not answer my question. (The edit by Wlod AA did not change the question -- where $y$ was free to choose in the complement of $U\cup\{x\}$).

Comment: @FernandoMuro : Details on my previous comment: The original claim/conjecture in my question (before the edit by Wlod AA) was of the form $\forall x\ \exists y\ \exists f\ \ldots$. Your counterexample disproves the much, much stronger claim (which I did not make or suggest), of the form $\forall x\ \forall y\ \exists f\ \ldots$. So, your answer does not address my question. (As I said, the edit by Wlod AA did not change the question at all, but presented it better, so that I accepted the edit, as a correct and useful one.)

Comment: @FernandoMuro: What if you use instead $X$:= the closure of the graph of
$$f(x):=x\sin\Big( 1/{\sin(1/x)}\Big)$$
Then $(0,0)$ can be connected to no point in $X$ by continuous arcs.

Comment: (this function has a set of discontinuities $\{\frac1{n\pi}:n\in\mathbb N\}$ that accumulates at $0$, but it is continuous at $0$, so the closure of its graph has no vertical pieces with $0$ first coordinate)

Comment: @IosifPinelis sorry, I misunderstood you.

Comment: @PietroMajer I think you’ve nailed it, you should post it as an answer.

Comment: @FernandoMuro : Should you then perhaps delete your answer?

Comment: @PietroMajer : Thank you for your comments. Could you please post them as an answer, so that I could accept it and finalize the matter?